# Baire measurable sets

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I got the following setting:

Let $X$ a uncountable set, $p \notin X$ and $X^* = X \cup \{p\}$. Let $$\mathcal O := \{O \subseteq X^* \mid O \subseteq X \text{ or } p \in O \text{ and } X \setminus O \text{ finite}\}.$$
Then $(X^*, \mathcal O)$ is a compact topological space and if $f \in C(X^*, \mathbb C)$, then $f(x) = f(p)$ for all $x \in X^*$ except for countably many.

$\operatorname{Ba}(X^*)$ denotes the Baire sigma algebra, i.e. the smallest sigma algebra which makes every $f \in C_c(X^*, \mathbb C)$ continuos.

Now the statement that I want to show:

$\{p\}$ is not Baire measurable, i.e. $\{p\} \notin \operatorname{Ba}(X^*)$.

I know the following. Since $X^*$ is compact I have $C_c(X^*, \mathbb C) = C(X^*, \mathbb C)$. So I guess I need to use that $f(x) = f(p)$ for all $x \in X^*$ except for countably many. But I dont see how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $C$ the collection of sets of countable subsets of $X$.

Define $U$ the collection of sets open sets $O_p$.

Claim $   {\rm BA}(X^{* })  \subset \sigma(C\cup U   )=S$, i.e. the smallest sigma algebra containing $C,U$.

Any subset now any set $A$ of $S$ can be expressed as a intersection of a countable union of sets belonging in $C\cup U$.

Now if $A=\{p\}$, then each term of the intersection must contain at least one set of the form $O_p$. However then $A$ is at least as big as a countable intersection of the form $  A\supset \bigcup O_p^{\alpha}$. But then this complement contains only finitely many elements and since $X$ is uncountable it $A$ cannot be a singleton.

To prove the claim take a continuous function $f$ from $X^*$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Take any $V$ open set of $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that $f(p) \in V$ then $f^{-1}(V)=O_p^{\beta}$. And otherwise if $f(p)\not \in V$ $f^{-1}(V)$, is a countable set.

Comment: What do you mean with "Define $U$ the collection of sets open sets $O_p$". Do you means the set of open sets that contain $p$?

Comment: @yaddle $U= \{ A\in \mathcal O| p \in A     \}$, yes exactly

Comment: Could you maybe clearify "However then $A$ is at least as big as a countable intersection of the form $  A\supset \bigcup O_p^{\alpha}$. But then this complement contains only finitely many elements and since $X$ is uncountable it $A$ cannot be a singleton"? I dont know what exactly is your argument there.

Comment: @Yaddle We would like to argue that $A$ cannot equal $\{p\}$ a singleton set. Since $X$ is uncountable is suffices to show that $A^{c}$ is countable, since then $A$ would be uncountable therefore not a singleton set.

Now $A \supset \bigcap _{n\geq 0} O_{p}^n $ for some collection of sets $Q_p^n \in U$.  Therefore $X-A \subset \bigcup _{n\geq 0} (X-O_{p}^n)$ and since $X-O_{p}^n$ is countable the complement of $A$ is countable.

Comment: The  $A \supset \bigcap _{n\geq 0} O_{p}^n $ comes from the fact that $A$ is a countable intersection of a countable union where in each countable union there must be at least one set of the form $O_p^n$.

Comment: Okay, thanks :)